# Grant file access to file downloads

Tags: 8, files, rules, ubercart

I am able to sell a file using Ubercart Drupal 8 module. However, file download permissions are not granted to the user purchasing the file.

Do we have a Rule in place for this? How can I achieve this?

I have a product which has two options: *Hard copy* and *E-book*. *E-book* is associated to a file download and with a role (*publication owner*) assignment option. Upon purchase, user should be granted publication owner, but this doesn't happen. Also, if I go to user/uid/purchased-files the file is not listed between the available downloads.

Comment: There could many reasons why there's no entry in uc_file_users. A better description of your config and error might help troubleshoot here.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart/issues/2763807 TR mentioned he has a code in core but where is that? Any idea?